# Are xml fragments allowed within asp.net core config?

Tags: asp.net-core

We have ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app, and one of the `appsettings.json` config sections has to have xml fragment as part of the section so it would look something like this. But settings up and running the app with the section like this resulted in exception. Tried number of things like replacing `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` but didn't help either. Hence the question - are xml fragments within `appsettings.json` config allowed or we need to look at other options?

```
{                                                                                                    
    "Configuration": "<key id=\"1bbaebea-31f4-465f-b0a7-a19d64944388\" version=\"1\"> 
    <value>zuX/fjZ35eRm4hgnFT2E3lQRPYF1IDJccboInH77Z+0DdMfZYVTg9+V5UkR0bK/DK1cXP6/ETn4/nlNrZOL62g==</value></key>"                                                                          
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [`Configuration providers in .NET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#xml-configuration-provider) first.

As we know, `appsettings.json` uses the `JSON configuration provider`.
The method used to call example.xml belongs to the [XML configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#xml-configuration-provider).

So it is not recommended to put xml in appsettings.json file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it's not recommended, but is it even allowed?